# Sql excxeption was unhandled by user code,Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I really dont know what is wrong with my Insert statement, it compains about unhandled user code. My insert on cmd looks fine as compared to other tutorials online.

```
public void retrieveData()
{
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[sqlconnectiostring].ToString())
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(sqlconnectiostring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FRUITSPRODUCT(@PRODUCTNAME,@PRODUCTTYPE,@Total) VALUES (@PRODUCTNAME,@PRODUCTTYPE,@Total)",conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTNAME","atlegang");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTTYPE","baby");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total","10");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Analyze the full exception. This is the first debugging step.

Comment: Also maybe not such a good idea to include your SQL Server password in the question!

Comment: The list of columns after the table name (`FRUITSPRODUCT`) needs to contain the **column names** of the table - and those most definitely **don't start** with a `@`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your insert-sql:

```
INSERT INTO FRUITSPRODUCT(@PRODUCTNAME,@PRODUCTTYPE,@Total) VALUES (,,)
```

This is the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO FRUITSPRODUCT(PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTTYPE,Total) VALUES (@PRODUCTNAME,@PRODUCTTYPE,@Total)
```